# Filter based on object field in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have four arrays of the same `object` which I use for a form.
They work as pairs such as `list_1` contains all possible values and `list_1_filtered` contains the choosen values, and the same goes with `list_2` and `list_2_filtered`.
The thing is that they can share similar objects with the same `object.id` and I want to filter it to not add values in `list_2_filtered` if it has the same `object.id` as any values in `list_1_filtered`.
So I did this :

```js
getList2(form_field_value:string){
    return this.list_2.filter(
        (e: /*Object*/)=>
            e.name.indexOf(form_field_value) != -1 &&
            this.list_2_filtered.indexOf(e)==-1 &&
            this.checkList2NotInList1(e)
    )
}

checkList2NotInList1(object: /*Object*/): boolean {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.list_1_filtered.length; i++) {
      if (object.id== this.list_1_filtered.at(i).id) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

But I find it quite unpleasant to use another function to filter based on `field` in my `object`.
Is there a better way to do it ?

**/!\** Names are changed for better understanding - please do not judge naming **/!\**

***UPDATE :***

class Object :

```
{
    id: string,
    itemName : string,
    quantity : number
}
```

Data in List 1 :

| id | itemName | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| J254 | corn | 154 |
| I465 | wheat | 169 |
| O25845 | strawberry | 200 |
| J365 | corn | 205 |

Data in List 1 filtered :

| id | itemName | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| J254 | corn | 154 |

Those works for a `tag` field in the form such as `list_1_filtered` contains the selected tags and `list_1` contains all possible tags.
Same goes for `list_2` & `list_2_filtered`

Data in List 2 :

| id | itemName | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| J254 | corn | 154 |
| P48612 | Pasta | 3010 |
| E754 | egg | 312 |
| J365 | corn | 205 |

Data in List 2 filtered :

| id | itemName | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| P48612 | Pasta | 3010 |

`getList2` is used when the `user` writes in the input field to return suggestions. But a tag can't be in `list_2_filtered` if its already in `list_1_filtered`. So `getList2` shouldn't return `{id:J254,itemName:corn,quantity:154}` if the user writes "J2" in the input field because `{id:J254,itemName:corn,quantity:154}` is already in `list_1_filtered`

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review community. Please don't change the names when posting the question. The code must be working code from a project you have written. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778).

Comment: Hey, name were also changef for privacy reasons --> client's name + the code is working well

Comment: @Neo are you able to give example datasets? So I can make sure I'm not misunderstanding your question

Comment: @JaniceZhong Updated the question with data and a bit mor explanation, hope that this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use Set?

```
const set = new Set([...list1, ...list2]);
const results = Array.from(set.values()).filter(item => item.name === object.name)
```

Might not be 100% suitable to your case, but you get the idea

Comment: Thanks, that's a pretty good idea didn't think about it. It would simply things, but yeah, using a set would be a difficult for the rest of my code, so not really suitable.

Comment: This answer is borderline for code review. Please read Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) and [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778).

Comment: FYI, your other 3 answers are good.